# Strange PayPal Express Checkout Issue only affecting users on iPhone/iPad using Facebook in-app browser

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, facebook, paypal

I've got a very strange issue with Paypal Express Checkout, its only an issue in certain conditons, otherwise it works perfectly fine.

Basically, if a user tries to purchase from our shop from an Apple mobile device (ipad or iphone) through Facebooks in-app browser and attempts to pay with Paypal (Other payment options are available) all they'll get is a blank white screen, and if they press the back button in the browser they go back to the product detail page, rather than the basket page they pressed the button on.

Unfortunately, our analytics show that at least 75% of our the monthly visitors to the entire website (Not just including the shop) use an iPhone or iPad, and probably at least 50%-60% of those are coming from Facebook.

The shop is custom built and I've got lots of logging set up to track the Paypal API calls, and the API calls are all running succesfully with no errors, and my logs show that the PayPal log in box should be appearing in the lightbox window, but it doesn't, when a user clicks the yellow 'Pay with Paypal' button through Facebook browser on an ipad/iphone it appears to open a new tab, but its just a blank page, and if I go to share the URL its just about:blank.

However, if a user uses the Safari app to purchase everything is fine, and everything is fine on Android devices, and on Windows computers and Apple computers.

I've spent the weekend trying to fix this issue, we even went out and bought an old second hand iPhone just to test on, rather than relying on friends, but I can't find anyone else with the same issue, or any way to fix it, as I said at the start, it works fine for everyone else except those on Apple and using Facebook's browser.

Below is the Javascript code that sets up the Paypal payment, pretty much all of it is from Paypal themselves from the examples in their Docs, and works in 90% of cases.

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'production', 
    commit: true,

    payment: function (resolve, reject) {

        var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'genPaypal.php';

        paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL) 
            .then(function (data) {
                resolve(data.id);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                reject(err);
            });            
    },

    onAuthorize: function (data) {
        // code here is executed when the user logs in to paypal and authorizes the purchase.
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

The `paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)` line sends a request to my PHP file which generates the API call, and as previously mentioned, the logs show this running as expected.

When the call is complete the user should be shown the PayPal log in box in a lightbox window, but just a blank page is loading.

As I said, it is only an issue if certain conditions are met, but it is loosing us business, and our logs show that we've easily lost £100-£200 of sales due to this issue in just a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the very detailed report! We're aware of this issue -- it's to do with the fact that opening a popup window inside a web-view inside an app is not possible.

We have this issue to track this: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/217 -- I'm hoping to get a fix out for this at some point this week.

For future issues, please feel free to raise github issues over at https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues -- we're more likely to see them there.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @bluepnume, I never thought of looking on Github, I didn't know if it was a Paypal issue, Facebook issue, or issue of my own making!

I'll keep an eye on the issue tracker on Github and in the mean time disable Paypal checkout for users coming in through Facebook's browser until a fix is applied.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please try this now? The issue should be resolved. Would be good to know if you see any further problems. Thanks!

Comment: Hi bluepnume, I was following the issue on Github, and when I saw that it had been marked as fixed and deployed I tested it on a local development version of the shop immediately and was very pleased to see that the lightbox window opened straight up through Facebook on an iPhone.

We enabled paypal checkout again through Facebook browser on iOS and we've seen lots of people checking out fine, thanks for fixing the issue quickly :)

Comment: Hi bluepnume, I didn't want to dig up this old thread, but I couldn't find a way of messaging you on here. Anyway, since you fixed the issue above things have been a lot better regarding users on apple devices through FB, but odd ones are still having the same issue with the box not appearing, and the only common factor is Apple devices, either iPhone or iPad, and using FB browser, every time the API gets as far as providing the login box to the user, but it doesn't appear. Sometimes it works second time, others it doesn't, but a lot of users also get through first time fine. Its very strange!

Comment: Hey @JamiePeters -- usually best to raise an issue over at https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues. I'll try to take some time this week to check out the FB browser on ios, and see if I can repro these issues. Thanks for letting me know!